# Installing and configuring email server on debian step by step

Tags: email-server

Can anybody tell me how to install and configure email server on debian step by step?

What I mean?

I have my own server with my dns. There are several sites on it. So I need:

1) Create emails for each domains, for example, admin@mydomain.com, admin@mydomain.net, admin@mydomain.org ... Where I can create them? Can I create that email list in file(s), not in mysql?

2) I need send emails from php scripts over smtp-server.

3) I need to read emails in Thunderbird (on Ubuntu, if that matters) and send emails from it over smtp of my domains.

I have already installed postfix and dovecot. What's next?

Can somebody provide me some HowTos?

Comment: http://wiki.debian.org/Network#Mail

Answer (score -1):

most probably you need to uninstall postfix and 
read that '[Handling mail for multiple virtual domains with exim4](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/140)'
as the exim4 is standard mta for debian, also you may be like to read 
[Dovecot virtual users](http://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/VirtualhostingWithExim)

http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html

Comment: "Posted by Steve on Mon 16 May 2005 at 15:46" - may be exist newer article?

Comment: why you need newer article ? almost nothing changed, check the second article from dovecot mailing list and exim4 specifications from exim.org